# how can i send form values to MYSQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending the answer values to the `answer` table. I do that with the following code. Please look at it and let me know where I do something wrong, I am new to php. 
I want add the question number and answer values to the table.

```
    <?php  
        //connects to database  
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
        if (!$con)  
        {  
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
        }  
            mysql_select_db("appulentoweb", $con);  

        //retrieve data from database  
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions"); ?>
 <form action="questioned.php" method="post">
       <table>
           <tr>
              <th> QNo</th>
              <th> QTitle </th>
              <th> QAnswer </th>
           </tr>
        <?php 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['qid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['qdesc'];?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="answervalue" /></td>
           </tr>
<?php  
$sql="INSERT INTO mobilestrgy (qno,response) VALUES ('$_POST[qid]','$_POST[answervalue]')";

?>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

I want to submit the data to database.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

- `die` isn't a good error handling function, nobody dies because of a mistake... Use good error handling instead, for an example: http://github.com/WouterJ/sql-boilerplate/tree/mysql/
- Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-assoc) instead of `mysql_fetch_array`
- Where do you check if the query has succeed?
- Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows) to check if the query has returned a result
- Don't put variables inside quotes. Use the dot operator: http://php.net/operators.string
- What is exactly go wrong? Do you get any errors? What is your database design?
- Where do you think the problem is? And what have you done before you ask it here? (e.g. searching on google)

Comment: okk thanks for your reply i want send that answer values to database along with qno.?

Answer (score 0):

You are learning, you need at least 2 files, one with the HTML code and the other with the PHP code.  When you click submit the HTML, it will send the data to the server and the PHP file will receive it, and insert it into the DB, take a look to this example

html page

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I took this from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Please review this REALLY [BASIC TUTORIAL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp), but will help you to understand

Comment: Please, don't use W3Schools... They are teaching you wrong methods

Comment: @WouterJ I would be agree with you if you already have some knowledge, but for me w3school is the "web development for dummies", because it's only to learn the basic

Comment: it is better to learn the good things immedately

Comment: i want send the title of the input text also how can i send?

Comment: @Wouter J - where would you recommend people go instead of W3schools?

Comment: can u take a look my code and correct my code ? where i am doing mistake ?

Comment: @Venkat you need to create another PHP file (questioned.php), please check the links I gave you.